# What happened to the Spring Security OAuth 2 documentation?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

The documentation for Spring Security OAuth2 seems to have completely disappeared.  The github project is moved to the "attic" but the old documentation is nowhere to be found. Anyone know where it is?

Comment: See https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth#overview. The project reached EOL. No more support. You have to migrate to Spring Security 5.

Comment: It's EOL, but not in my codebase.  I installed it 6 years ago, and now there's no documentation online so I can understand how the whole thing works.  The source code is still visible in Github, why am I not allowed to view the documentation?

Comment: I don't know. I guess it is a cleanup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the project has reached end of life and the repository put in the spring-attic, it appears the documentation is still available in the gh-pages branch. See https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth/blob/gh-pages/docs/Home.md .

Comment: Dang!  That would have been useful a whiles back!   Thanks for the pointer.